# Three trees: What's the chance of having at least one male and one female?

Tags: probability

**I have 3 trees.**

- These particular trees are dioecious (male or female).
- I don't know the gender of any of the trees.
- The chance of a tree being male or female is 50/50.
- I need at least one male and one female for successful pollination to occur.

**What are the chances that I have at least one male and one female tree?**

Comment: Another Hint: Binomial Distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $M$ denotes male tree, $F$ — female tree. The probability is 
$$
1-P(MMM)-P(FFF).
$$
But, from independency, $P(MMM)=P(M)P(M)P(M)=(1/2)^3$.

BTW: What are female trees? Have they a hollow? ;-)

Comment: Some species are dioecious; each tree having either male or female flowers.  Eg: Willow, Juniper, Teak...

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you. I knew such other plants, but not trees.

Comment: @Wilson Please see my extended hint. Can you finish now?

Comment: @Wilson Oh, sorry! Misprint. Corrected. So $1-(1/8)-(1/8)=3/4$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a binomial distribution with $n=3, p=\frac12$. Let $X$ shows the number of male trees, then:
$$P(X=1)+P(X=2)={3 \choose 1}\left(\frac12\right)^1\left(\frac12\right)^{3-1}+{3 \choose 2}\left(\frac12\right)^2\left(\frac12\right)^{3-2}=\\
3\cdot \frac12\cdot \frac14+3\cdot \frac14\cdot \frac12=3\cdot \frac14=\frac34.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here are all of the [possible combinations](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html) that I can come up with:

```
{M,M,M} 
{M,M,F} 
{M,F,M} 
{M,F,F} 
{F,M,M} 
{F,M,F} 
{F,F,M} 
{F,F,F}
```

There are a total of 8 possible combinations. Of the 8, only 6 of them have at least one male and one female.

Therefore, I think the probability of getting at least one male and one female is `6 / 8 = 75%`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my layman's interpretation of @PrzemysławScherwentke's answer:

`1` - `(1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2)` - `(1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2)` = `.75`